# Pandas merge overwriting lists in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = 
   product_name  image                          barcode
    'test_1'     ['test_1.png', 'test_2.png']   '12345'


df2 =
   product_name  image                          barcode
    'test_1a'     ['test_a1.png', 'test_a2.png']   '12345'


merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer' on='barcode', indicator=True, suffixes=('_supplier_1', '_supplier_2')
```

```
#result

   merged_df['image_supplier_1'] = ['--0.png', '--1.png']
   merged_df['image_supplier_2'] = ['--0.png', '--1.png']
```

How do I prevent mutation in the list upon merge, as later I want to concatenate the images on both columns. Many thanks

Comment: @Manlai thank you for you help. It turns out when I was exporting it to csv it was altering the data. Otherwise in the Dataframe it was unaltered. I cant believe I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when I was exporting it to csv it was altering the data. Otherwise in the Dataframe it was unaltered. I cant believe I missed it